# Javascript inheritance - what happened to "this"?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, this

I have this prototype chain :

Object -> Prototype of Panel -> Prototype of IllustrationPanel -> Prototype of ModernPW3IllustrationPanel

Some functions of ModernPW3IllustrationPanel are inherited from IllustrationPanel.

But when I'm calling one of these inherited function, ModernPW3IllustrationPanel are now 'null'.

Here's my code :

```
function Panel(n, t){
    this.name = n;
    this.title = t;
    this.element = null;
}

Panel.ID_PREFIX = 'fcm-panel-';
Panel.CLASS_TOGGLE = 'active';

Panel.CONTAINER_ELEMENT = $('.fcm-panel-container');
Panel.MENU_ELEMENT = $('#fcm-menu');
Panel.TEMPLATE_CONTAINER_ELEMENT = $('#fcm-template-panel');
Panel.TEMPLATE_MENU_ELEMENT = $('#fcm-template-menu');

Panel.prototype.getId = function(){ return Panel.ID_PREFIX + this.name; }

// Retourne l'élément jQuery du panneau /!\Il peut être vide, si le panneau n'a pas été chargé
Panel.prototype.get = function(){ return Panel.CONTAINER_ELEMENT.find('#' + this.getId()); }

// Appelé quand le panneau est affiché
Panel.prototype.onFocus = function(){
    // À redéfinir
}

// Appelé quand le panneau est caché
Panel.prototype.onBlur = function(){
    // À redéfinir
}

// Appelé quand le panneau est activé
Panel.prototype.onActivate = function(){
    // À redéfinir
}

/**
 * Affiche le panneau et met son lien du menu en surbrillance
 */
Panel.prototype.show = function(){
    this.get().addClass(Panel.CLASS_TOGGLE);
    Panel.MENU_ELEMENT.find('[data-panel="'+this.name+'"]').parent('li').addClass(Panel.CLASS_TOGGLE);
    this.onFocus();
}

/**
 * Cache le panel
 */
Panel.prototype.hide = function(){
    this.get().removeClass(Panel.CLASS_TOGGLE);
    Panel.MENU_ELEMENT.find('[data-panel="'+this.name+'"]').parent('li').removeClass(Panel.CLASS_TOGGLE);
    this.onBlur();
}

/**
 * Ajoute le panel au menu et l'active
 * (Le contenu du panel doit déjà avoir été ajouté au DOM)
 */
Panel.prototype.activate = function(){
    Panel.TEMPLATE_MENU_ELEMENT.append('<li><a href="#" data-panel="'+this.name+'">'+this.title+'</li>');
    this.element = $('#'+Panel.ID_PREFIX+this.name);
    this.onActivate();
}





function IllustrationPanel(n, t){
    Panel.call(this, n, t);

    this.cropSelector = null;
}
IllustrationPanel.prototype = Object.create(Panel.prototype);

IllustrationPanel.prototype.onFocus = function(){
    // Gestion du plugin ImgAreaSelect
    //console.log('illustration onFocus');
    console.log(this.cropSelector);
    if(this.cropSelector != null){
        this.cropSelector.setOptions({show:true, hide:false});
        this.cropSelector.update();
    }
}

IllustrationPanel.prototype.onBlur = function(){
    // Gestion du plugin ImgAreaSelect
    console.log('illustration onBlur');
    console.log(this.cropSelector);
    if(this.cropSelector != null){
        this.cropSelector.setOptions({show:false, hide:true});
        this.cropSelector.update();
    }
}

IllustrationPanel.prototype.onActivate = function(){

    var varthis = this;

    Panel.CONTAINER_ELEMENT.on('uploadSuccess', '#fcm-form-illustration', function(){
        varthis.onImageLoad();
    });

    Panel.CONTAINER_ELEMENT.on('uploadFailure', '#fcm-form-illustration', function(){
        varthis.onImageUnload();
    });

    Panel.CONTAINER_ELEMENT.on('click', '#fcm-illsutration-center-viewport', function(){
        varthis.centerImage();
        return false;
    });
}

IllustrationPanel.prototype.onImageLoad = function(){
    var image = this.element.find('.file-preview');
    var centerbutton = this.element.find('#fcm-illsutration-center-viewport');
    centerbutton.addClass('active');
    image.load(function(){
        // init imgAreaSelect
        centerbutton.trigger('click');
    });
}

IllustrationPanel.prototype.onImageUnload = function(){
    var image = this.element.find('.file-preview');
    var centerbutton = this.element.find('#fcm-illsutration-center-viewport');
    centerbutton.removeClass('active');
    image.imgAreaSelect({remove:true});
}

IllustrationPanel.prototype.centerImage = function(){

    // init imgAreaSelect
    var form = this.element.find('form');
    var image = form.find('.file-preview');
    var axis = true;    // true = X(portait), false = Y(paysage)
    if(image.width() / image.height() > myFuncard.illusWidth / myFuncard.illusHeight)
        axis = false;
    //console.log(axis);

    var cx1 = 0, cx2 = 0, cy1 = 0, cy2 = 0;

    if(axis){
        cx2 = image.width();
        var height = image.width() / (myFuncard.illusWidth / myFuncard.illusHeight);
        //console.log('height:', height);
        cy1 = (image.height() - height) / 2;
        cy2 = cy1 + height;
    } else {
        var width = image.height() * (myFuncard.illusWidth / myFuncard.illusHeight);
        //console.log('width:', width);
        cx1 = (image.width() - width) / 2;
        cx2 = cx1 + width;
        cy2 = image.height();
    }

    form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-x').val('');
    form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-y').val('');
    form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-w').val('');
    form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-h').val('');

    //console.log(cx1, cy1, cx2, cy2);

    this.cropSelector = image.imgAreaSelect({
        instance: true,
        handles: true,
        persistent: true,
        aspectRatio: myFuncard.illusWidth + ':' + myFuncard.illusHeight,
        x1: cx1,
        y1: cy1,
        x2: cx2,
        y2: cy2,
        onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
            img = $(img);
            var px = selection.x1 / img.width();
            var py = selection.y1 / img.height();
            var pw = selection.width / img.width();
            var ph = selection.height / img.height();
            form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-x').val(px*100);
            form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-y').val(py*100);
            form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-w').val(pw*100);
            form.find('#fcm-field-illuscrop-h').val(ph*100);
        }

    });

}




function ModernPW3IllustrationPanel(n, t){
    IllustrationPanel.call(this, n, t);
}
ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.prototype = Object.create(IllustrationPanel.prototype);

ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.prototype.centerImage = function(){
    IllustrationPanel.prototype.centerImage.call(this);

    if(this.cropSelector != null){
        this.cropSelector.setOptions({classPrefix:'mpw3-imgareaselect', handles:true});
        this.cropSelector.update();
    }

    console.log(this.cropSelector);
}

// (...)

existingPanels['mpw3-illustration'] = new ModernPW3IllustrationPanel('illustration', 'Illustration');
```

*IllustrationPanel.prototype.centerImage is called when "centerbutton" is clicked, and when an image is loaded*

My problem is the following :

- When I load an image, this.cropSelector is well initialized : the `console.log(this.cropSelector);` in `ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.prototype.centerImage` prints the good $.imgAreaSelect object.
- When I call `ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.onBlur` (so the prototype hierarchy calls `IllustrationPanel.prototype.onBlur`), the console.log() statement prints `null`.
- -> Where is my $.imgAreaSelect object gone ? :(

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I may be mistaken, but when you directly call the parent prototype, your calling a method on the prototype, not on the class instance, so it wouldn't be set. Not to get too much into inheritance, but the issue you're having is that the prototype doesn't inherit your data, your object inherits the methods from the prototype and therefore when called directly `this` refers to the prototype method, not the instance

Comment: So, how can I tell to `IllustrationPanel.prototype.centerImage` to be called from my ModernPW3IllustrationPanel object ?

Comment: @Thaledric If you expect people to take some time and effort to help you solve your problems, you should also take some to reduce the code to a [mimimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I misunderstood. Try adding `ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.prototype.constructor = ModernPW3IllustrationPanel` below the Object.create line

Comment: `function ModernPW3IllustrationPanel(n, t){
        IllustrationPanel.call(this, n, t);
    }
    ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.prototype = Object.create(IllustrationPanel.prototype);
    ModernPW3IllustrationPanel.prototype.constructor = ModernPW3IllustrationPanel;`

It not seems to work. :/

(Is there any way to make multi-line code blocks in comments ?)

Comment: No, there is not. Make sure you're actually calling centerImage before calling onBlur

Comment: The walls to centerImage and onBlur are delayed in time.
A click event calls centerImage, another independant click event calls onBlur.
It is sure that centerImage is called after onBlur.

Comment: Should I use `IllustrationPanel.prototype = Object.create(Panel);` instead of `IllustrationPanel.prototype = Object.create(Panel.prototype);`